# How to adjust my toString method to work with multiple inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string, printf, tostring

This is sloppy but it works with printint a 6x6 2D array and 4 arrays on each side of it:

```
  1 4 2 2 2 3 
 --------------
1 | 0 0 0 2 0 0  | 4
3 | 3 4 0 0 0 0  | 2
3 | 0 0 0 1 0 0  | 2
2 | 0 1 0 0 0 0  | 4
6 | 0 0 0 0 0 6  | 1
2 | 5 0 1 0 0 4  | 2
 --------------
  2 1 3 4 3 2  
null
```

Can anyone help me adjust this method to work with any size array? Not just a 6x6?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.print(' ');
    System.out.print(' ');
    for(int i = 0; i < NS.length; i++){
        System.out.print(NS[i]);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (i % board.length == 0) {
            System.out.println(' ' + "--------------");
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (j % board.length == 0) {

            for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
                System.out.print(WE[r]);
                System.out.print(" | ");
                for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {
                    System.out.print(board[r][c]);
                    System.out.print(' ');
                }
                System.out.print(" | ");
                System.out.print(EW[r]);
                System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    System.out.println(' ' + "--------------");

    System.out.print(' ');
    System.out.print(' ');
    for(int i = 0; i < SN.length; i++){
        System.out.print(SN[i]);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
    return null;
}
```

`NS` is top array on the top

`SW` is the array on the bottom

`WE` is the array on the left

`EW` is the array on the right

and `board` is the 2D array

here is a 7x7 result:

```
  1 4 2 2 2 3 4 
 --------------
1 | 0 0 0 2 0 0 1  | 4
3 | 3 4 0 0 0 0 0  | 2
3 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  | 2
2 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  | 4
6 | 0 0 0 0 0 6 0  | 1
2 | 5 0 1 0 0 4 0  | 2
4 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  | 2
 --------------
  2 1 3 4 3 2 3 
null
```

here is a 4x4 result:

```
  1 4 2 2 
 --------------
1 | 0 0 0 2  | 4
3 | 3 4 0 0  | 2
3 | 0 0 0 1  | 2
2 | 0 1 0 0  | 4
 --------------
  2 1 3 4 
null
```

Comment: Are the horizontal lines the only things that don't print correctly if you print more than 6x6?

Comment: I edited in more example outputs. I just want everything to straighten out and not have a null get returned

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using `toString` to print to the console. You should either return a `String` and print that or use a different method name.

Comment: In my assignment, I'm told to use toString. I just don't know how to return this representation in toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString` needs to return a `String`, so instead of returning null, you should build a `StringBuffer` and return that - no `System.out.print`s.  the horizontal lines can be achieved with `StringUtils.repeat`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("  ");
    for(int i = 0; i < NS.length; i++){
        sb.append(NS[i]+" ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("   " + StringUtils.repeat("-", board.length) + "\n");
```

etc...

```
    return sb.toString();
}
```

now that your object properly implements toString(), you can just print your object.

```
System.out.println(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question. I created a string and added to it using basically the same logic.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
    table.append("    ");

    for (int i = 0; i < NS.length; i++) {
        table.append(NS[i]);
        table.append(" ");

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (i % board.length == 0) {
            table.append("\n");
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++){
                table.append(" ");
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < board.length * 2; a++) {
                table.append("-");
            }

        }
    }

    table.append("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (j % board.length == 0) {

            for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
                table.append(WE[r]);
                table.append(" | ");

                for (int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {
                    table.append(board[r][c]);
                    table.append(" ");

                }
                table.append("| ");
                table.append(EW[r]);
                table.append("\n");

            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (i % board.length == 0) {

            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++){
                table.append(" ");
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < board.length * 2; a++) {
                table.append("-");
            }

        }
    }
    table.append("\n");
    table.append("    ");

    for (int i = 0; i < SN.length; i++) {
        table.append(SN[i]);
        table.append(" ");


    }
    return table.toString();

}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`, not string concatenation. This will create hundreds of short-lived objects for each call.

Comment: But my toString returns a String, not a StringBuilder

Comment: Read the documentation on `StringBuilder`. The last thing you'll do is `return builder.toString()`.